# How to not increase setInterval then called several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is there is possibility to not increase set interval speed after calling it several times. I'm doing the auto scroll function. After you hit the selected speed button it calls the function `setInterval`. My problem that more I hit button page scrolls faster and faster. how to solve my logical mistake?

```
function scroll() {
  var scrollspeed = document.getElementById("scrollspeedval").value;
  if (scrollspeed == 1) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 1);
  } else if (scrollspeed == 2) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 2);
  } else if (scrollspeed == 3) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 4);
  } else if (scrollspeed == 4) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 8);
  } else if (scrollspeed == 5) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 12);
  } else if (scrollspeed == 0) {

  };
}

$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".scrollcl").click(function() {
    var interval_for_autoscroll = setInterval(function() {
      scroll();
    }, 400);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why is "setInterval" inside the event handler rather than outside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should stop the already running interval timer using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) before starting the new one:

```
clearInterval(interval_for_autoscroll); // where interval_for_autoscroll is declared outside the scope of the callback.
```

Something like this:

```js
function scroll() {
  var $object = $('.object'),
      angle = $object.data('angle') || 0;

  $object
    .css({ 'transform': 'rotateZ(' + angle + 'deg)' })
    .data('angle', (angle + 10) % 360);
}

$("document").ready(function() {
    var interval_for_autoscroll;
    $('.slow').click(function() {
        clearInterval(interval_for_autoscroll);
        interval_for_autoscroll = setInterval(scroll.bind(window), 400);
    });
    $('.normal').click(function() {
        clearInterval(interval_for_autoscroll);
        interval_for_autoscroll = setInterval(scroll.bind(window), 100);
    });
    $('.fast').click(function() {
        clearInterval(interval_for_autoscroll);
        interval_for_autoscroll = setInterval(scroll.bind(window), 10);
    });
});
```

```css
.object {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="object">
</div>
<button class="slow">slow</button>
<button class="normal">normal</button>
<button class="fast">fast</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using JQuery, I suppose [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) might be a better option for you, if you only want the event to trigger once.

You could try something like this:

```
$(".scrollcl").one("click",function(){});
```

Comment: The OP has multiple buttons with different speeds... So `one()` will not help here.